# In Xml remove node value not the entire node

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder

In Xml How to remove node value in flex4.

Here it is the example.This is my xml node.

```
<item label="">R1</item>.
```

I want remove R1 in the above xml.

I need the output like this `<item label=""></item>` or `<item label=""/>`. This is possible? if Possible Please help me.

```
<result>
  <item label="Room3">

    <item>G140213003048</item>
  </item>
  <item label="Room4">Room4</item>
  <item label="Room8">Room8</item>
  <item label="Room149">Room149</item>
  <item label="Room53">Room53</item>
</result>
```

How To remove empty space in xml.@Adrian Pirvulescu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

Considering your xml is declared like this

```
var myXML:XML = new XML(<item label="">R1</item>);
```

You can do the following:

```
myXML.setChildren("");
trace(myXML.toXMLString());
```

--
Output:   `<item label=""></item>`

**UPDATE**

Since you updated your example I need to update my post as well. 
Since you want to remove only in nodes where @label is "" then you can use the following.

```
resultXML..item(@label == "").setChildren("");
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you need Empty node? But still if you want it do like so,

Assuming your xml has only one node,

```
var xml:XML = <item label="">R1</item>
xml.replace(0, <item></item>);
```